# Birkas haTorah: Can you read any piece of Torah?

Tags: blessing, torah-study

When we make birkas haTorah in the morning, we follow it up with Bemidbar 6:24-26 (יברכך...), followed by the beginning of Peah in the Mishna and Tosefta. Do those sections need to be read? If I wanted to bentsch birkas haTorah in order to learn something specific, can I make the berakha and then just launch straight into what I *wanted* to learn?

Answer (score 4):

The language of the Rambam in Hilchos Tefillah 7:11 is

> בכל יום, חייב אדם לברך שלוש ברכות אלו, ואחר כך קורא מעט מדברי תורה. ונהגו העם לקרות ברכת כהנים, ויש מקומות שקורין "צו את בני ישראל", ויש מקומות שקורין שתיהן. וקורין פרקים או הלכות מן המשנה או מן הברייתות
>
> Every day a person is obligated to make these three blessings, and afterwards to read a section from words of Torah. And **the custom is** to read *Birkas Kohanim*, and there are places where they read "*tzav...*" (Numbers 28), and some places read both. And we read chapters or halachos from Mishna or Baraisos.

So, the obligation is just words of Torah, and the particular sections are custom.

I have heard before that the custom to read specifically verses, Mishna, and Baraisa is based off of Berachos 11b, which debates whether each of the three require the blessing.

Additionally, there are some commentaries who attribute particular significance to the three sections that we read, although nothing amounting to an obligation to those three.

Lastly, R' Moshe Einstadter in Cleveland told me that he used to substitute verses from Eicha on Tisha B'Av because of the issue of learning on Tisha B'av, but he stopped at some point.

Comment: Shulchan Aruch OC 47:9 seems to indicate similarly, that it’s only out of a potential concern that we say these.

Comment: @DonielF you are a fast reader. Thanks, I'll add that in.

Comment: @DonielF sorry, how do you see that there? All I see in that se'if is יש אומרים שאם הפסיק בין ברכת התורה ללמודו אין בכך כלום והנכון שלא להפסיק ביניהם וכן נהגו לומר פרשת ברכת כהנים סמוך לברכת התורה

Comment: @Y  e  z While technically there’s no problem with interrupting between the Bracha and the learning, one shouldn’t do so, which is why we say Birchas Kohanim. Implying that one can say any Torah, as long as it’s immediately afterwards.

Comment: @DonielF oh my bad, I misunderstood you to be referring to my next comment about why we say all 3. The stronger implication from the Mechaber is "וכן נהגו", that it is only minhag to say birkas Kohanim

Comment: @Y  e  z may I kindly draw your attention to this: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-10th-birthday-lets-divide-and-conquer-the-entire-mish/5050#comment16158_5050 re your interest to learn a chapter in tractate Megila. Is it still the case? Thanks